# Gradient with transparency

Tags: html, css

Gradient with transparency![enter image description here][1]

I wanted to apply transparent multicolor gradient at the bottom like the below picture.
I've found few pages which explains this but still i'm unable to get it working properly.

I tried with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QEhsG/2/ (found on stackoverflow)  but im not able to get black and white combination perfectly.

Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `alpha= 0` to your first **rgba**. Write like this

```
button {
    background-color: black;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252, 252, 252, 0) 0%, rgba(186, 186, 186, 1) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252, 252, 252, 0) 0%, rgba(186, 186, 186, 1) 100%);
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/QEhsG/6/

UPDATED

http://jsfiddle.net/QEhsG/8/

Comment: thanks sandeep but when i use this it does it give me the effect what is needed it looks more like a block of element...